# Function for mouse near an element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I want to track and show a tooltip when the mouse is near a table head element. It works with the `mouseenter` event, but I want show the tooltip before `mouseenter`, when it gets near. Also I want remove the tooltip after `mouseout` some distance from the table head.

This is my code:

```js
$('thead').mouseenter(showtooltip);
$('thead').mouseout(removetooltip);
```

How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: Give your div margins on all sides, margins and padding are counted as part of the object so if you mouse over the margin then you will see the tooltip before you 'actually' enter the div.

Comment: Or, create a larger transparent div positioned over your target div, and set the event handlers on this invisible div.

Comment: thank you ryanOptini. I want do it for table head. not for div

Comment: As nrabinowitz said - you could position transparent div over table head and then trigger the mouseenter / mouseout events on thead by hand.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This works. The first parameter can be any jQuery object. The second parameter is the nearness to the object, in this case `20px`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/Lpg8x/

Script:

```js
$( 'body' ).mousemove( function( event ) {

    if( isNear( $( 'thead' ), 20, event ) ) {
        //show your tooltip here
    } else {
        //hide it here
    };

});           

function isNear( element, distance, event ) {

    var left = element.offset().left - distance,
        top = element.offset().top - distance,
        right = left + element.width() + 2*distance,
        bottom = top + element.height() + 2*distance,
        x = event.pageX,
        y = event.pageY;

    return ( x > left && x < right && y > top && y < bottom );

};
```

Comment: This solution seems to be rather CPU-heavy