# jQuery Animation expanding Divs in Circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I don't know how to search for this in google or at least here at stackoverflow. Maybe you guys have a word for this animation to search for or something how to call it.

Anyway, my idea is the following. You have a simple div and when you click on it, from the center of the div there should grow 4 other divs which have a little distance to the clicked div and are placed on a half circle. Maybe the image can help your imagination to follow my idea:
[image]

Does anyone of you have an idea how to code this?

Edit: Added Code from Comment, while .squadplayerinfo are the spread divs, .playercard the outer div and .field the outer outer div

```
function calculateDistance(elem, mouseX, mouseY) {
    return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - (elem.offset().left + (elem.width() / 2)), 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offset().top + (elem.height() / 2)), 2)));
}

$(document).on("mousemove", ".field", function(e) {
    var mX, mY, distance,
    $element  = $(".playercard");

    mX = e.pageX;
    mY = e.pageY;
    distance = calculateDistance($element, mX, mY);

    if(distance > 100) {
        $(".squadplayerinfo").each(function(index) {
            (index == 1 || index == 2) ? radius = 100 : radius = 75;

            angle = toRadians(360 / $(".squadplayerinfo").length * (index + 0.5) / 2);

            $(this).animate({
                opacity: 0,
                right: "+=" + calcX(angle),
                top: "+=" + calcY(angle)
            }, 750, function() {
                // done animating
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with the idea for a few minutes and I think this is what you are looking for:

```js
// javascript
var amount = $(".expand").length;
var radius = 200;

$("#trigger").click(function() {
  var x, y, angle;
  $(".expand").each(function(index) {
    angle = toRadians(360 / amount * index);
    x = calcX(angle);
    y = calcY(angle);
    $(this).animate({
      right: "-=" + x,
      top: "-=" + y
    }, 2000, function() {
      // done animating
    });
  });
});

function calcX(angleRadians) {
  return Math.floor(radius * Math.cos(angleRadians));
}

function calcY(angleRadians) {
  return Math.floor(radius * Math.sin(angleRadians));
}

function toRadians(angleDegrees) {
  return angleDegrees * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

```css
/* css */

.expand {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
}
#trigger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  right: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!-- html -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expand">a</div>
<div class="expand">a</div>
<div class="expand">a</div>
<div class="expand">a</div>
<div class="expand">a</div>
<div class="expand">a</div>
<div class="expand">a</div>
<div class="expand">a</div>

<button id="trigger">click me</button>
```

It is dynamically computes the angles based on the amount of `div`s and the radius can be controlled with ease :)

Hope this helped... Good luck

### EDIT

I have noticed you only want your `div`s to spread on the top half of the screen, so pls change this line:

```
angle = toRadians(360 / amount * index);
```

to this one:

```
angle = toRadians(360 / amount * (index + 0.5) / 2);
```

### EDIT#2

Since HansMartin has edited his post, this is a snippet which will move the div when the mouse will come near the divs (or any other div specified). This snippet is using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7920345/6338083) answer to check proximity to the div.

```js
// javascript
var amount = $(".expand").length;
var radius = 200;
var first_animation = true;

$('#check-mouse-area').mousemove(function(event) {
  if (first_animation) {
    if (isNear($(".expand"), 200, event)) {
      first_animation = false;
      var x, y, angle;
      $(".expand").each(function(index) {
        angle = toRadians(360 / amount * (index + 0.5) / 2);
        x = calcX(angle);
        y = calcY(angle);
        $(this).animate({
          right: "-=" + x,
          top: "-=" + y
        }, 2000, function() {
          // done animating
        });
      });
    }
  }
});

function calcX(angleRadians) {
  return Math.floor(radius * Math.cos(angleRadians));
}

function calcY(angleRadians) {
  return Math.floor(radius * Math.sin(angleRadians));
}

function toRadians(angleDegrees) {
  return angleDegrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

function isNear(element, distance, event) {

  var left = element.offset().left - distance,
    top = element.offset().top - distance,
    right = left + element.width() + 2 * distance,
    bottom = top + element.height() + 2 * distance,
    x = event.pageX,
    y = event.pageY;

  return (x > left && x < right && y > top && y < bottom);

}
```

```css
.expand {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
}
#check-mouse-area {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- html -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="check-mouse-area"></div>
<div class="expand">a</div>
<div class="expand">a</div>
<div class="expand">a</div>
<div class="expand">a</div>
<div class="expand">a</div>
<div class="expand">a</div>
<div class="expand">a</div>
<div class="expand">a</div>
<div class="expand">a</div>
```

The main change is from

```
$("#trigger").click(function () {
```

to

```
$('#check-mouse-area').mousemove(function (event) {
...
if (isNear($(".expand"), 200, event)) {
```

Since the mouse mousemove event is called **a lot** I added the `first animation` boolean so that the animation will only fire once.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! In advance to your code, I centered all divs by another click, but I would like to center all divs, when the mouse is for example 100px away from the middle div. Any idea how to do this? I tried so far with the mousemove event, but couldn't get it done. Added code was edited in my post.

Comment: @HansMartin Sorry, I can't understand exactly what you are looking for in this edit. 
Do you mean that this animation should run when the mouse is near the divs and not when a button is clicked?